# Is it possible to put one button naming initiate and an another button naming stop over each other

Tags: android, button

Like when the start button is pressed the so the start button should hide and stop button should be visible. How should i put the buttons one over another. i want both buttons on the same place.

Comment: so why not just making a selector?

Comment: No actually i want buttons

Comment: :) . Selector is a xml defined layout for things like You want. You press the button and then the view changes. look here for a simple example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

Comment: just setVisibility gone to first button and in the class when click one button hide other and same for second button.Positioning is the same for the two button.Is this is correct for your question?

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` it'll keep your button at the same place, unless you define different layout params.

Comment: i know that visibility thing. i just want to know how to put two buttons on the same place

Comment: i think the code that i post you early works fine for your case.I hope so :)

Comment: you can mark the answer as correct if some of the answers is help you to got it ;)) , if you want of course :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/firstButton"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/secondButton"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the java class

```
public class YourClass extends Activity {

    private Button first,second;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        first = (Button)findViewById(R.id.firstButton);

        second = (Button)findViewById(R.id.secondButton);

        first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                second.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                first.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        second.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                second.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                first.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout and inside that take two buttons(both parents align top or bottom as u desire).
Initially hide the stop button. On clicking of Start Button , hide start button and make stop button visible. Here is example

```
 <RelativeLayout        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startBTn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:gravity="center"            
        android:text="Start"/>        
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopBTn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:gravity="center"            
        android:text="Start"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```